# Config file content as checkbox list in jenkins

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

I have a config file in Jenkins which contains list of servers. Which running parameterized job pipeline I would like to list it and choose the server where the code can be deployed. 
How can I write that in "groovy template for pipeline" area as xml?

Config file content:file.txt

Server1

Server2

Server3

A Checkbox list should come to select the servers.

Comment: Have you looked for plugins, e. g. Extended/Extensible Choice Parameter?

Comment: Thanks. I am looking for syntax on how to read config file content and populate to this extensible choice parameter

Comment: can you explain your use case in more detail? and why you are limited to solve this with a code-only solution (since Extendible ChoiceParameter is not an option)?

Comment: Basically the xml code is already present and need to enhance it . Jenkins gives a solution to generate pipeline syntax . But to generate xml syntax there is not option . Also documentation is limited

Answer (score 0):

Make a new pipeline project.
Enable the option 'The project is parameterized'. Then choose the check box option. I used active choice reactive .
Here we can have type as checkbox. Save it once.
Now take the job history and we can view the XML of the project. From this the XML can be copied and used.